# ansible playbook errors out while trying to to run python script

Tags: python, ansible

while doing rolling restart of cluster using ansible i want run python script to verify the rebooted came back without any issues. so i'm trying to run the python script passing arguments using ansible. below is the code i'm using it fails

ERROR! this task 'python' has extra params, which is only allowed in the following modules: command, win_command, shell, win_shell, script, include, include_vars, include_tasks, include_role, import_tasks, import_role, add_host, group_by, set_fact, raw, meta

```
- hosts: tag_name
  gather_facts: yes
  become: true
  serial: 1
  tasks:
    - name: execute python script
      local_action: python script.py -r us-east-1,us-west-2 -n tag -e test -s tag -k "pemfile" -u ec2-user
```

Comment: For future reference, when you paste preformatted code into the post, immediately select it and type Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button in the interface. That will format the code properly.

Comment: sure thanks. will do that next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the error is correct as 'command' and 'shell' are two most common modules for which you can specify the arguments. To execute the python script on the local host with arguments, use 'command' along with 'local_action' as below.

```
local_action: command python script.py -r us-east-1,us-west-2 -n tag -e test -s tag -k "pemfile" -u ec2-user
```

Comment: to use command i need to copy the script to remote node and inside the python script i'm using some files in the same repo. woudn't have access from the machine i'm sshing to. i want to run the python script locally.

Comment: tried  failed with sudo error. so it tries ssh from remote host back to my local machine? fatal: [myhost -> 127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "failed": true, 
    "module_stderr": "sudo: a password is required\n", 
    "module_stdout": "", 
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", 
    "rc": 1

Comment: it worked if i make the gather_facts: no. can i use same play-book few commands to run on remote host and few on local?

Comment: the delegate_to directive can be used to select specific hosts for specific tasks. I believe you can try running your original code by adding the 'command; module. Try this:  `local_action: command python script.py -r us-east-1,us-west-2 -n tag -e test -s tag -k "pemfile" -u ec2-user`

Comment: I'm trying to run one command in remote host then run the python script from local if use below its trying to ssh from remote machine to local
`- hosts: tag
  gather_facts: yes
  become: true
  serial: 1
  tasks:
    - name: Reboot task
      command: /sbin/reboot
    - name: execute install script
      local_action: command python script.py -r us-east-1,us-west-2 -n tag -e test -s tag -k "pemfile" -u ec2-user`

Comment: i want to to proceed to second node only if the python script executes successfully after the first node reboot is finished

Comment: Hello, I think your original issue in this question can be addressed by using this format --> `local_action: command python script.py`. I tested this on my system and it executed successfully on my localhost. I have updated the answer to the original question.

Comment: Thanks @dhillonfarms. do you know if the second ask is possible?

Comment: Hi @cad, yes it is possible although I would need to review the task again but I would really suggest you to create a brand new question on that topic and I am sure it will get lots more visibility from the folks around here. Good luck!